# Android displaying two arraylists with different types into one seamless listview using adapters

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I have a custom `ArrayAdapter` of a base class. I also have a subclass and I want the `ArrayAdapter` to be able to receive two different types of data i.e. (arrayList and arraylist)and display them consecutively in one seamless `listview`.

I have never done this before so general comments and guidelines are much appreciated. I tried to make the ArrayAdapter generic:

```
public class MyAdapter<T extends BaseClass> extends ArrayAdapter<T>
```

with this constructor:

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<T> items) {
        super(context, 0, items);
        fullList = items;  
    }
```

But I do not know how to then pass a generic ArrayList that can either have type subclass or base class. (and this approach will later involve code that uses instanceOf which is not the best way to do things ... as I have learned from SO)

Instead of generics, I was thinking of extending this custom `arrayadapter` itself. But I am not sure how this would work.

What is the best way to approach this? Is there maybe a better adapter suited for this case other than `arrayadapter`. Or could it be that `recyclerview` has a solution to this problem?

I ultimately want to have two similar but different types of datasets (one subclassed another), outputted as one seamless listview. I was not able to find the general approach to doing this.

Answer (score 0):

What datatypes are you using in your ArrayLists?

If, for instance, Strings and Integers, could you not convert the values and merge into a single ArrayList?

```
for (int i=0; i<arraylist1.size(); i++) { //arraylist1 containing integers

arraylist2.add(Integer.toString(arraylist1.get(i));

}
```

then you can just apply the one ArrayList to a standard ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Not really no. the data types are my own custom base class and another subclass

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using view type.

example:

row_type_one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTypeOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

row_type_two.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTypeOne"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

YourTypeOne.java

```
public class YourTypeOne{
    public String title;
}
```

YourTypeTow.java

```
public class YourTypeTow {
    public String title;
    public String imgUrl;
}
```

YourAdapter.java

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.YourViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();

    public YourAdapter(ArrayList<YourTypeOne> typeOneArray, ArrayList<YourTypeTow> typeTowArray) {
        objects.addAll(typeOneArray);
        objects.addAll(typeTowArray);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return objects.get(position) instanceof YourTypeOne ? 1 : 2;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public YourViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;
        if (viewType == 1) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.row_type_one, parent, false);
        } else {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.row_type_two, parent, false);
        }
        return new YourViewHolder(v,viewType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull YourViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    class YourViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView txtTypeOne;

        private TextView txtDescription;
        private ImageView logo;


        public YourViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, int vewType) {
            super(itemView);

            if (vewType==1){
                //find views by ides in .xml
                txtTypeOne =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTypeOne);
            }else {
                //find views by ides in row_type_two.xml
                txtDescription =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
                logo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
            }
        }


        public void bindeData(Object object){

            if (object instanceof YourTypeOne){
                //set data to layout row_type_one
            }else {
                //set data to layout row_type_two
            }

        }


    }
}
```

good luck. :)